# Bash: split multi line input into array

Tags: bash, array, split

I've got a file with strings and base64 encoded data over multiple lines, that are sepearated by a comma.

Example:

```
1,meV9ivU4PqEKNpo5Q2u2U0h9owUn4Y8CF83TTjUNWTRQs7dEgVxnsMgf4lvg9kvxcIaM3yB4Ssim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=,U2FsdGVkX1/c8rTTO41zVT7gB+KL+n7KoNCgM3vfchOyuvBngdXDGjXTvXTK0jz6
```

Now, I'd like to split the content into an array, so that each multi-line string is an array element.

I tried to use IFS, but that only reads the first line:

```
filecontent=$(cat myfile)
IFS=',' read -a myarray <<< "$filecontent"
```

Result:

```
$myarray[0] = 1 
$myarray[1] = meV9ivU4PqEKNpo5Q2u2U0h9owUn4Y8CF83TTjUNWTRQs7dEgVxnsMgf4lvg9kvxcIaM3yB4Ssim
```

Expected:

```
$myarray[0] = 1
$myarray[1] = meV9ivU4PqEKNpo5Q2u2U0h9owUn4Y8CF83TTjUNWTRQs7dEgVxnsMgf4lvg9kvxcIaM3yB4Ssim
z46M/C7YlovNUmrjOByhV1SCb/bGyv1yL7SYFnw1GHbYjdH0b6UZ7nQzJHU6VmwMo0V77vFNy6nx
rmJZ4KqW9EcjdV1plQmsVXSiZVi61+fNOHCMDmVtJ4q097geWxf4bT0/k/yRyRwi5Zr8BC64htVS
AdwOSo4PIk7xDLOzLywAYOCDQvD/zuErf1L0e8nHGz2LKdApHdEWB7Y2yM3iZyXuQ4sMx0+oX66+
FxwUulvHj+EpXtLJx5rmV7AUjr/GsNw/1aYAGPCfz0S+//Ic5pXX5rY1fZ96oFGw4a9vRiAmxe/w
ZOza6LtwuF+WUHjbIeWTUKKQGgFIM81dwVHHY7xdRnQhK5J0Zf3Xz0GzzZj5/2YFbI8q7lVkJ3ZQ
7Oqt0qdfk3aj+BQhOxmn1F55yACPBZoPUw6K8ExTHHGVGdCEiIDTu5qKHcUwK0hGAZA9Mun5KTO0
gPs9JxF8FJjkQBF7rEa6TP3pH5OwdkATH2uf+Zcmp1t6NbBymXVlsLzWZookVsaT1DNXf1I1H8Xz
8dnfh6Yl63jSr2PAhDrcOqJNM8Z9/XhBGxtlD1ela3nq6N1ErR1Gv1YZKNeNcL7O2Z3Vl2oyyDw=
$myarray[2] = U2FsdGVkX1/c8rTTO41zVT7gB+KL+n7KoNCgM3vfchOyuvBngdXDGjXTvXTK0jz6
```

Could someone help me out here?

Comment: AFAIK, `read` only reads up to a newline; you *may* be able to get it to work the way you expect by explicitly setting the delimiter to the null character i.e. `IFS=',' read -d '' -a myarray ...`

Comment: You may want to look into the [Practical Extraction and Reporting Language](http://learn.perl.org/tutorials/) for your extraction and reporting needs....

Comment: Also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823706), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628076).

Answer (score 6):

Your attempt is close to the actual solution. The relevant flag can be found in the `read` help:

```
$ help read
...
      -d delim  continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
            than newline
```

It doesn't explicitly mention it, but you can set the delimiter to empty, and thus it'll read until EOF.

```
$ IFS=, read -d '' -a myarray < myfile

$ echo ${myarray[2]}
U2FsdGVkX1/c8rTTO41zVT7gB+KL+n7KoNCgM3vfchOyuvBngdXDGjXTvXTK0jz6
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `read` builtin will return a non-zero exit status upon encountering an EOF, so if you have set `-e` somewhere in your shell script as the [_Bash Strict Mode_](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) document suggests, you better mask the exit code of `read`, e. g.: `read -a myarray -d '' -r <<< "${raw_content}" || true`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try newline on `IFS` like
`IFS=$'\n' read -a myarray <<< "$filecontent"`

The reason I am suggesting `$'\n'` is  because bash doesn't interpret escape sequences in string literals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that in your expected result, the first instance of $myarray[2] should have been $myarray[1].

You can achieve the desired result by stripping the embedded newlines before assinging the file's content to the shell variable:

```
filecontent=$(tr -d \\n <myfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-d ''` to read whole file instead of just one line.

```
 -d delim   continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
            than newline
```

```bsh
$ cat file.txt 
abcd
efgh
$ IFS=$'\n' read -a ARR < file.txt
$ echo ${#ARR[@]}
1 # only 1 element
```

```bsh
$ IFS=$'\n' read -a ARR -d '' < file.txt
$ echo ${#ARR[@]}
2 # whole file
```

One more thing:
Make sure you don't have `set -e` in your script if you are using `-d ''`, as the `read --help` says (at the end):

```
 Exit Status:   
    The return code is zero, **unless end-of-file is encountered**...
```

```bsh
$ IFS=$'\n' read -a ARR < file.txt
$ echo $?
0
$ IFS=$'\n' read -a ARR -d '' < file.txt
$ echo $?
1 # Your script will exit if you `set -e`
```